# In Euclidean space, can open ball be written as the direct product of open sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in \mathbb R^n, $ $B(a,r)=\{ x\in \mathbb R^n \mid \| x-a\|<r \}$.

Can $B(a,r)$ be written as the direct product of open sets in $\mathbb R$,
i.e., are there $U_1, \cdots, U_n \in \mathcal O_{\mathbb R}$ s.t. $B(a,r)=U_1\times \cdots \times U_n$ ?

$B(a,r)$ is $B(a,r)=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\mid x_i\in \mathbb R, \sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+\cdots+(x_n-a_n)^2}<r\}$, and I have difficulty in finding such $U_i.$ For example, $U_i=\{y\in \mathbb R \mid |y-a_i|<r\}$ doesn't work.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Do not answer questions via commments, write proper answers. Copy and paste will do here.

Comment: @PaulFrost 1) No, for my standards it wouldn't have been enough. 2) I want my answers on this site to be easily accessible to me, so I can't quite answer frequently. 3) When I leave a sketch of proof like it was (and isn't anymore) in this case, people can just take the idea and use it themselves: I sure don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

It can't.

For convenience, assume that $n=2$. And assume that there exists open sets
$U, V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $B(0,1) = U \times V$, i.e.,

$$ B(0,1) = \{ (u,v) ~ : ~ u \in U, ~ v \in V \} . $$

If $-1 < x < -1$, then there exists $-1 < y_x < 1$ such that $(x, y_x) \in B(0,1)$.

Thus $(x, y_x) \in \{ (u,v) ~ : ~ u \in U, ~ v \in V \}$ for every $-1< x< 1$.

It implies that the open interval $(-1, 1) \subset U$.
(Because if $-1 < t < 1$, then $(t, y_t) \in U \times V$,
which implies that $t \in U$ and $y_t \in V$.
Thus $(-1,1) \subset U$.)

In the same way, we obtain that $(-1, 1) \subset V$.

However, we know that $B(0,1) \subsetneq (-1,1) \times (-1,1)$.

Thus, it can't.