# The equivalence of two definition of Euclidean topology.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

The common definition of open set of $\mathbb R^2$ is $$U\subset \mathbb R^2 \ \mathrm{is \ open} \ \iff \forall a\in U, \exists r>0 \ ; \ B_2(a,r)\subset U,$$ where $B_2(a,r)$ is an open ball around $a$ with radius $r.$

Thus, Euclidean topology is $\mathcal O_{\mathbb R^2}=\{ U\subset \mathbb R^2 \mid \forall a\in U, \exists r>0 \ ; \ B_2(a,r)\subset U\} \cdots (A)$

On the other hand, it is possible to define Euclidean topology of $\mathbb R^2$ as a product topology of
$(\mathbb R, \mathcal O_{\mathbb R})$ and $(\mathbb R, \mathcal O_{\mathbb R})$.

Specifically, let $\mathcal B=\{U\times V \mid U\in \mathcal O_{\mathbb R}, V\in \mathcal O_{\mathbb R}\},$ then
the product topology $\mathcal O_{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R}=\mathcal O_{\mathbb R^2}$ is the topology whose base is $\mathcal B$, i.e., $\mathcal O_{\mathbb R^2}=\{ U\subset \mathbb R^2 \mid \exists  \ \mathrm{index\ set }\ \Lambda, \exists \{B_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in \Lambda}\subset \mathcal B \ ; \ U=\cup_{\lambda\in \Lambda}B_\lambda \}\cdots (B)$

I want to check the equivalence of $(A)$ and $(B)$.

---

Let $(A)=\mathcal M, (B)=\mathcal N.$

I proved $\mathcal M\supset \mathcal N,$ but I have difficulty in proving $\mathcal M\subset \mathcal N$.

Here is my proof and this doesn't seem to work.

Let $U\in \mathcal M.$

Then, $\forall a\in U, \exists r_a>0 \ ; \ B_2(a,r_a)\subset U$, thus $U=\displaystyle\bigcup_{a\in U} B_2(a,r_a)$ holds.

So if I show $\{B_2(a, r_a)\}_{a\in U}\subset \mathcal B$, I can say $U\in \mathcal N$ and the proof will finish.

For this, I have to show $\forall a\in U, \exists U, V \in \mathcal O_{\mathbb R}, B_2(a, r_a)=U\times V$,

However, from the comment in this post [In Euclidean space, can open ball be written as the direct product of open sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491192/in-euclidean-space-can-open-ball-be-written-as-the-direct-product-of-open-sets), such $U,V$ doesn't exist, so this proof doesn't work.

How can I show $\mathcal M\subset \mathcal N$ ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be any set and $\tau, \tau'$ be two topologies on $X$ with basis $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B'}$ respectively.

Then $\tau\subset \tau'$ if for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$ and $\forall x\in B$ there exists a $\tau'$-basic open set $B'$ such that $x\in B'\subset B$

---

For the euclidean topology on $\Bbb{R}^2$ basic open sets are all open balls $\{B_2(x,r) : x\in \Bbb{R^2} ,r>0\}$

For the product topology on $\Bbb{R}^2$ basic open sets are all open rectangles, $\{(a,b)×(c,d) : a, b, c, d\in\Bbb{R} ,a<b,c<d\}$

---

Intuitively, if we choose a point from a open disk, we can place an open rectangle containing that point and contained in the open disc. In ther words a disc is arbitrary union of open rectangles.

And

If we choose a point from a open rectangle, we can place an open disc containing that point and contained in the open rectangle. In ther words an open rectangle is arbitrary union of open disc.

---

Thus two bases are equivalent and generates same topology.

Comment: So, in order to show $\mathcal M\subset \mathcal N$, what I should show is (i) $\{B_2(x,r)\mid x\in \mathbb R^2, r>0\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal M$, (ii) $\{(a,b)\times (c,d)\mid a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R, a<b, c<d \}$ is a basis of $\mathcal N$, (iii) $\forall B\in \{B_2(x,r)\mid x\in \mathbb R^2, r>0\}, \forall x\in B, \exists B'\in \{(a,b)\times (c,d)\mid a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R, a<b, c<d \}$ s.t. $x\in B'\subset B$ ?

Comment: Basis of the product topology os the product of the respective basis